# Technology behind stupeflix and/or animoto

Tags: flash, animation, video, web

I am trying to learn the technology stack behind StupeFlix and Animoto. I find the whole process very interesting and it is amazing how both of them are able to create professional looking videos so quickly.

As far as I can tell they use a combination of Flash based animations and after effects. Does anyone know the whole process? ie. if I were to create my own stupeflix, what kind of technology, servers etc would I need?

This question is targeted towards learning new technology so please feel free to modify my question to reflect that better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stupeflix is not based on Flash, but on a custom OpenGL stack.
Stupeflix has indeed some tools to convert automatically After Effects projects into Stupeflix ones, so artists can easily produce stuff for the platform, but After Effects is not part of the rendering pipeline, as it would be way too slow: After Effects is all about quality, not speed.
Hope it will help you build the next Stupeflix or Animoto ;-)

François, CTO @ Stupeflix

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am interested to know more about your conversion or execution of after effect scripts. How does that get executed on the server side?

Comment: We have a special script that convert After Effects Projects to a valid Stupeflix XML with placeholders for text and images. We don't support every AE features in the conversion process, but quite a good amount of them.